# Add Generic item in array in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I want to add a generic item in an array. How do I achieve it in following method:

```
    func get<T: Decodable>(from url : URL, type: T.Type, completion : @escaping (Result<T, ApiError>) -> ()) {
//            messages.append((url, completion))
        }
        
        var messages : [(url: URL, completion: (Result<Codable, Error>) -> ())] = []
```

I am getting following error when I try to append:

> Cannot convert value of type '(URL, (Result<T, ApiError>) -> ())' to
> expected argument type '(url: URL, completion: (Result<any Decodable,
> ApiError>) -> ())'

I am using get function to return api response as a generic model and trying to use above code in my test cases.
I believe I need to specify that array is expecting a generic item but I am not sure how to achieve it.

Edit:
original function for which I am writing tes case:

```
public func getTimeTable() -> AnyPublisher<TimetableModel, Error> {
    Future { [weak self] promise in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        httpClient.get(from: url, type: TimetableModel.self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let timeTable):
                promise(.success(timeTable))
            case .failure(let error):
                promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing the completion handlers in an array in the first place? What are you planning on doing with them? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I want to write test case for condition that get function(from dependancy class) has been called

Comment: Just added an edit showing function detail

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that without erasing the type. To do that, you can declare the type of `messages` property as `[(url: URL, completion: (Result<Any, ApiError>) -> ())]`

and your `get` would become something like this:

```
func get<T: Decodable>(from url : URL, type: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, ApiError>) -> ()) {
    let typeErasedCompletion = { (result: Result<Any, ApiError>) in
        completion(result as! Result<T, ApiError>) // or use optional binding
    }
    
    messages.append((url, typeErasedCompletion))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store non specific items of a generic type, you need to declare an intermediate protocol like this:

```
protocol MessageProtocol<ResultType, ErrorType> {
    associatedtype ResultType: Codable
    associatedtype ErrorType: Error
    associatedtype CompletionType = ((Result<ResultType, ErrorType>) -> ())

    var url: URL { get }
    var completion: CompletionType { get }
}

struct Message<ResultType: Codable, ErrorType: Error>: MessageProtocol {
    let url: URL
    let completion: CompletionType
}

struct ApiError: Error {}

func get<T: Codable>(from url : URL, type: T.Type, completion : @escaping (Result<T, ApiError>) -> ()) {
    messages.append(Message(url: url, completion: completion))
}

var messages : [any MessageProtocol] = []
```

Not sure if `Decodable` was important – just changed it to `Codable` in `get` function.